# Python - rewrite byte array with 0x00 for each hex byte read in

Tags: python

I'm currently investigating ways of bypassing basic signature detection on antivirus products.  Right now, I'm trying to break up a file by padding with 0x00 (maybe NOPs are better?) but I can't figure out how to do this.  I'm writing an incredibly simple Python script to automate obfuscation of binaries to bypass basic detection (to prove a point in my paper) and this is the final snippet.

So far, I've only read the executable into a bytearray, I'm now trying to figure out how I would read each hex value, write it to a new array, write 0x00, take the next hex value from the first array and continue.

```
Example
a = 54 68 69 73 20 70 72 6F 67 72 61 6D 20 63 61 6E 6E 6F 74 20 62 65 20 72 75 6E 20 69 6E 20 44 4F 53 20 6D 6F 64 65 (DOS stub)
```

I'm looking to pad/insert 00 in between each hex value to have the following

```
b = 54 00 68 00 69 00 73 00 20 00 70 etc.
```

Is there a simple way of going about this?

Comment: `[x for t in zip(a, [0]*len(a)) for x in t]` like this?

Comment: Could you post valid python so we can get some hint as to which types you're using? Are a and b supposed to be python2 strings, or python3 bytes, or a list of integers? Could you also indicate if you're using python 2 or 3, because bytestring handling is done differently between the two.

Answer (score 2):

`b''.join(bytes(x) for x in zip(a, itertools.repeat(0)))`

Comment: Having a few issues with this.  Would it not be 00 also?

Comment: This is only compatible with python 3, for python 2 you want (something like) `''.join(str(bytearray(a)) for a in zip(x, itertools.repeat(0)))`

Answer (score 0):

Join you list of hex values with `' 00 '`!

```
# when type of a is of <type 'bytearray'> 
>>> b = ' 00 '.join(str(a).split())
>>> print b
54 00 68 00 69 00 73 00 20 00 70 00 72 00 6F 00 67 00 72 00 61 00 6D 00 20 00 63 00 61 00 6E 00 6E 00 6F 00 74 00 20 00 62 00 65 00 20 00 72 00 75 00 6E 00 20 00 69 00 6E 00 20 00 44 00 4F 00 53 00 20 00 6D 00 6F 00 64 00 65
>>> b = bytearray(b) 
>>> print b
bytearray(b'54 00 68 00 69 00 73 00 20 00 70 00 72 00 6F 00 67 00 72 00 61 00 6D 00 20 00 63 00 61 00 6E 00 6E 00 6F 00 74 00 20 00 62 00 65 00 20 00 72 00 75 00 6E 00 20 00 69 00 6E 00 20 00 44 00 4F 00 53 00 20 00 6D 00 6F 00 64 00 65')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That would make sense.  Although, I see 'a' in your example.  What is 'a' defined as in your example?

Comment: TypeError: 'bytearray' object is not callable

Need to keep in mind that the bytearray is populated with hex bytes from a file like such.

    b = bytearray(open("C:/Users/Analysis/Desktop/spora", 'rb').read())

I assume I have to do some sort of data conversion here?

EDIT:  I've also just realized that this isn't reading the file in and saving as individual hex bytes.

Comment: what is the type of your input(what you have given as `a` in the question)?

Comment: I have no 'a' in my question, only 'b' which is the bytearray.  Makes more sense to change it to 'a' from a reading perspective.  I'll clean that up.

Comment: You can have it as a string and then convert it to the desired type! maybe `res.split()` to get it as a list of str or even `bytearray(res)`